# Let Z:G->H be a group Homomorphism and g an element of G. Prove that Z(g)^|g| = e?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I know that A group homomorphism is a map between two groups such that the group operation is preserved: for all , where the product on the left-hand side is in and on the right-hand side in. But i dont know how to prove the above statement.

Comment: I took the liberty of writing explicitely the definition of a group homomorphism (it seemed you wanted to do so and then forgot?)

Comment: Later, you use this to prove that the images of a character of a finite group are roots of unity.  (See the first 40 pages of J.-P. Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*.)

Answer (score 1):

$$Z(g)^{|g|} = \underbrace{Z(g) \cdot Z(g) \cdots Z(g)}_{|g|} = Z(\underbrace{g \cdot g \cdots g}_{|g|})$$

Comment: Can you provide me with the detailed solution

Comment: @remal Can you provide us with your attempts to solve the problem or whether you understand our hints or whether a particular step confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By induction on $n$ you can prove that 
$$Z(g)^n=Z(g^n)$$